# Add JS to specific pages AFTER all other JS

Tags: 7, theming, javascript, google-maps

I am working with JSON to theme Google Maps in the api v3.

I have my custom JSON script as an external JS file, and I am currently referencing it in html.tpl.php after the other scripts are loaded. This works great, and maps are themed, but on any pages that don't have a GMAP on them, i get the following error in Dev Tools...

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addHandler' of undefined"

So I am trying to add the JS file to just the pages that have a GMAP, in template.php I use the following under the MY_THEME_preprocess_page function.

> if (isset($vars['node']) && $vars['node']->type == 'venue') {
>       drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'MY_THEME') . '/js/mapstyle.js');   }

This loads the JS for all pages that are of the content type "Venue". The problem I am having is that the JS file is loading BEFORE the gmap scripts, and the style is not being rendered.

How do i get a JS file to load after all of the other scripts? I also need to load the JS file on a views page mysite.com/venues , but as a views page doesnt have a "node/id" alias, I am struggling to figure out how to only load the JS on that page using template.php

Comment: Adding js in the tpl.php is a recipe for disaster. Read [this](https://drupal.org/node/756722). Then make your code a behavior, that's a must have. Include them in info file, or turn them into a library (or two, with dependency between them). Then we'll have a chance o actually think about making it work. But first thing first, make it a behavior and show us how it looks now (may and even should be a trimmed version, we don't need to know your magic ;) only parts relevant to the issue).

Comment: Hi Molot, what is the big No No with adding drupal_add_js to a template file? On that page you sent me, it looks like adding an array with weight associated with it would solve my problem?

Comment: Well if you add js in tpl file, you can't know if it will be added to a page, as templates are heavily cached. So it's a bit of lottery what gets stored into cache, which list of js will really get used. Only logic you can safely put inside tpl is "if row is odd, add a class" and similar stuff. Everything even a tad more advanced about display logic, should be done in template.php. For the js themselves, most supported method is to use `'[#attached']` in renderable array or info files. `drupal_add_js` is only a "fallback" for situations where you can't use any of these safer ways.

Comment: Ah ok, yeah that makes sense. Thank you for explaining it to me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the following in my template.php file for my theme, I achieved what I wanted to do.

```
function MY_THEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if (isset($vars['node']) && $vars['node']->type == 'venue') {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'MY_THEME') . '/js/mapstyle.js',
    array('weight' => 15));
  }
}
```

I couldn't add the JS to my .info file as it would add to all pages, so I used the drupal_add_js fallback in template.php, and the now the error no longer shows on a page that doesn't have a GMAP on it.